# Unit Test: Cannot use ArgumentCaptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to create a unit test for the following method that calls another private method:

```
public CommandDTO create(final LabelRequest request) {
        return saveLabel(new Label(), request);
}

private CommandDTO saveLabel(final Label label, final LabelRequest request) {
        label.setName(request.getName());
        final Label saved = labelRepository.saveAndFlush(label);

        return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(saved.getUuid()).build();
}
```

It returns "nullpointer exception for the `saved` parameter as I did not mock in in my test.

Here is the Unit Test. I added 2 question as comment (Q1 and Q2). Could you please clarify me what is wrong?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LabelServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private LabelRepository labelRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private LabelServiceImpl labelService;
        
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<Label> labelCaptor;

    @Test
    public void test_create {
            
        // Q1: I am not sure if the following parts are needed
        final LabelRequest request = new LabelRequest();
        request.setName("Label Name");
        final Label label = new Label();
        label.setName(request.getName());


        // Q2: I think there is no need to mock saveAndFlush method. 
        // But in this scene it returns "nullpointer exception"
        when(labelRepository.saveAndFlush(any())).thenReturn(label);


        CommandDTO result = labelService.create(request);

        Mockito.verify(labelRepository).saveAndFlush(labelCaptor.capture());
        final Label value = labelCaptor.getValue();
                
        // then make necessary assertions
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you create a mock for the repo at all?

Comment: @daniu Yes, of course (I updated the question)

Comment: Please post full stacktrace explaining WHAT is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: @dominicoder `saved` variable is null, that means `labelRepository.saveAndFlush(label)` is not mocked. But I think I do not need to mock it.

Comment: Notice that I asked you to post a full stacktrace that explains what is actually throwing a null pointer exception and instead of doing that you're re-explaining your question that is incomplete and unclear. If you want help solving your problem, you need to provide as much information as possible to help us understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

**F I R S T**

I think that you only declared your mocks but never defined/created them. There's basically three ways to do so:

**1) mockito extension**

The convenient way in JUnit 5 is to use the MockitoExtension:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LabelServiceImplTest {

  // declare mocks, spies and captors ...

  // system under test
  @InjectMocks
  LabelService sut;

}
```

Nothing else should be needed now.

Mind that by `@InjectMocks` you instruct Mockito to create your system under test and inject the mocks. You may as well do that manually, e. g. by injecting mocks into the SUT's constructor. I prefer that way to have more control over the configuration of my SUT.

**2) MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(testclass)**

This method will inject mocks into the given object:

```
public class LabelServiceImplTest {

  // declare mocks, spies and captors ...

  // system under test
  @InjectMocks
  LabelService sut;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMock(this)
    
    // ...
  }

}
```

On JUnit 4 you'd use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(…)` instead.

**3) the old school way**

```
public class LabelServiceImplTest {

  LabelRepository labelRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(LabelRepository.class);

  // ...

  // system under test
  LabelServiceImpl sut;


  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    sut = new LabelService(labelRepositoryMock);

    // ...
  }

}
```

---

**S E C O N D**

Your questions …

**1) Do you need to create the request and the label?**

Yes. You call the service using the request and the mock returns the label. I would suggest you do *not* use the request's property to set up your label, use a `String` literal instead.

**2) Do you need to mock the saveAndFlush() method?**

Yes. This is the part where you configure your SUT's environment to behave in a predictable way.

---

You might consider postfixing your mocks, spies and captors by: "Mock", "Spy" and "Captor".
You might also consider calling your system under test "sut".

```
@Mock
private LabelRepository labelRepositoryMock;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Label> labelCaptor;

// system under test
@InjectMocks
private LabelServiceImpl sut;
```

This makes the test code more readably, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. I am not sure if the FIRST part is related to my situation, because there is nothing wrong with definitions. Could you please post a full example test?

Comment: Try adding the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` to your test class and see what happens! As I wrote I got the impression that you did not *define* your mocks, newither did you actually create the system under test. You just declared that they *should* be created – which the `MockitoExtension` as well as `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(...)` would do for you.

Comment: I do not think that I need them, because all the other examples are defined as in my code.

Comment: From what I see you defined *neither* `LabelService` (system-under-test) *nor* `LabelRepository` (mock). You declared both but they are still `null` as you never defined them. You've got your answer. I'd appreciate you reading it to the end, trying it out and pushing the accept button here if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. But you mentioned the parts that I have no problem. Instead of these points, why do not you concentrate on the problematic part?